# Has anyone used ComponentOne XAPOptimizer for a real production Silverlight Application?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, obfuscation, xap, componentone

In particular any experiences using it for obfuscation?  How does this affect binding, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't affect bindings. You might need to use the pro version if you use reflection (directly or indirectly), but it really works.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you download the desktop version of [silverlight optimization](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/XapOptimizer/) to use instead of the online version. It is much more powerful and is what you want to try for production apps. It is free for 60 days then time bombs. If it works well for you, it is definitely worth the money. It will save a lot of bandwidth for you and your end users.